# Git in Powershell no longer picking up aliases defined in .gitconfig

Tags: git, powershell

I use git largely from a Powershell window.  I've just upgraded to the latest Windows build 1903 and all of a sudden, the git alias I defined in `%userprofile%/.gitconfig` is no longer recognized:

```
[alias]
    lazy = "!f() { git add -A && git commit -m \"$@\" && git push; }; f"
```

The error I get is:

```
git: 'lazy' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

The most similar command is
        blame
```

Why is it not seeing the alias?  How can I troubleshoot this?

P.S.  If I run git from the CMD prompt - it works perfectly fine.

P.P.S. I looked to see what process is accessing .gitconfig in the powershell console and it turns out that it's looking for the file in the `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\etc` folder rather than my home folder.

Comment: In CMD is working?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Yes, it works in CMD.